# Are some users removed from past moderator election?

Tags: discussion, moderators, moderator-election

Was visiting the [2014 moderator election nomination phase](https://stackoverflow.com/election/5?tab=nomination) and have the feeling that some candidates may have been removed from the page.

For instance there was this guy, his name was a formula, H2CO3 [edit: confimed by @InfiniteRecursion], and he doesn't appear anywhere in the nomination page. I remember well him being there, because he had a peculiar profile and got many rather negative comments.

Are some candidates removed from the nomination page after the election ends?

Comment: This guy you mentioned was rage quitting the site IIRC.

Comment: Yeah, it was an epic rage-quit. Not too many people are able to just throw away an account with 100k+.

Comment: So he left and his nomination was removed automatically?

Comment: He requested that his account be deleted.

Comment: [He left SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/176228/h2co3)

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion That's him! And his election nomination page is not accessible anymore, even as userxxxx?

Comment: @ring0: his nomination was withdrawn before the primary phase, IIRC. Withdrawing at that point removes the nomination post entirely.

Comment: "Rage quit" isn't exactly the right term.  He was a very caustic user, rubbed many people the wrong way.  Very smart but with social graces of a thermonuclear device.  When he decided to run for moderator, everybody that he ever insulted showed up at the same time trying to talk him out of it.

Comment: Ah, my brother from another mother...  I miss him.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Logically, if a candidate withdraws his nomination or otherwise ceases to be a member of SO, then he/she would have to be removed from the election. You can't vote for a user that decides not to continue in the election or is a non-existent user.